# Modifying facts in Drools with Scala

Tags: scala, drools

(Drools newbie here) I've been looking around for ways to load objects (facts) into Working memory and modify them  through rules. From what I've found so far I think I should be using the "modify" instruction in the rule consequence but can't find much about it. I've also come across a link that makes use of modifyObject which supposedly takes 2 arguments, swapping out the old object for a new object [http://legacy.drools.codehaus.org/Working+Memory].

Considering that I'm using Scala objects (i.e. immutable), is this the way to go (retracting old object, inserting new)? And if so, can anyone provide an example of such code?

Comment: This link is to a page created in 2006. It is more than obsolete.

Comment: Granted :) Couldn't find any further documentation on them modify or modifyObject methods mentioned though (which seemed to do what I needed) so thought it was worth a check. I believe your answer does about the same thing actually

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use the update call with two arguments, even though you have to retrieve the fact handle:

```
 when
     $s: Sale(...)
 then
     Sale s = new Sale( $s,... );
     update( kcontext.getKieRuntime().getFactHandle( $s ), s );
 end
```

delete and insert may cause more work in the network than update.

Note that other Drools features cannot be used when modify is not available. Using functional scala in combination with using fact updates in a production rule system that depends on fact modifications for creating new activations is somewhat contradictory approach.

Comment: Quick question about this (trying it out)...Do you need to pass the kcontext in as a global or is it readily accessible within the rules? I'm using IntelliJ and the Drools plugin isn't too great with suggestions

Comment: kcontext is readily available. - See the doc, section "Right hand side".

Comment: Think this should be fine. Only thing I'm stuck on now is creating the new object. I've got a scala method which I can call to pass back the new object I need but not sure how to handle object creation on the RHS.
Still having IDE troubles (IntelliJ plugin isn't all that great) so I'm not entirely sure if my (Scala-Drools) syntax is fine or not. Is it just a case of writing something like:

   `then
        SampleObject b = objectCreationFunction(param1, param2)
        update(kcontext.getKieRuntime().getFactHandle($b), b)`